# SQL Server: How to update table based on subquery in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table (with data) like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[lTab](
    [log_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JobName] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [startTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [endTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [BatchId] [int] NULL,
    [status] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [messag] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[lTab] ON
INSERT [dbo].[lTab] ([log_id], [JobName], [startTime], [endTime], [BatchId], [status], [messag]) VALUES (1, N'Job1', CAST(0x00009EB700FBF56F AS DateTime), NULL, 2, N'START', N'Test')
INSERT [dbo].[lTab] ([log_id], [JobName], [startTime], [endTime], [BatchId], [status], [messag]) VALUES (2, N'Job2', NULL, CAST(0x00009EB700FBF975 AS DateTime), 2, N'START', N'Test')
INSERT [dbo].[lTab] ([log_id], [JobName], [startTime], [endTime], [BatchId], [status], [messag]) VALUES (3, N'Job3', CAST(0x00009EB700FC287F AS DateTime), NULL, 2, N'START', N'Test')
INSERT [dbo].[lTab] ([log_id], [JobName], [startTime], [endTime], [BatchId], [status], [messag]) VALUES (4, N'Job3', NULL, CAST(0x00009EB700FC2CC6 AS DateTime), 2, N'END', N'Test')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[lTab] OFF
```

I'm trying to update endTime based on Jobname and max(log_id).

```
DECLARE @Jname VARCHAR(10)
SET @Jname = 'Job3'

UPDATE lTab
SET endTime = GETDATE() 
WHERE log_id = (SELECT JobName, MAX(log_id) AS log_id FROM dbo.lTab WHERE jobname = @Jname GROUP BY JobName)
```

I get an error

```
sg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

How to get this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the `Jobname` from the select list in the subquery.

You don't actually need it to get the result you need, SQL Server will still return the right log_id.

What you have won't work since you are returning 2 fields (`Jobname`,`MAX(Log_id)`) and trying to match `Log_id` to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobName ORDER BY log_id DESC) AS rn
        FROM    lTab
        WHERE   JobName = @Jname
        )
UPDATE  q
SET     endTime = GETDATE() 
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Isn't the CTE overkill though, since all he needs is one field and he can get it by excluding `Joblist` from the fields in the subquery?

Comment: @JNK: `CTE` is not as expensive as it may look. In this very case it will be actually optimized to `TOP`, and by removing the `WHERE` clause all latest `log_id` can be updated with a single statement. Using a subquery will require an extra key lookup so the `CTE` is actually more efficient in this case (probably several milliseconds faster!)

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
(SELECT JobName, MAX(log_id) AS log_id FROM dbo.lTab WHERE jobname = @Jname GROUP BY JobName)
```

is returning multiple results, exclude JobName from your query.

Answer (score 0):

Yet a better option would be

```
UPDATE tablename SET tablename.field1 = sourceTable.dataField
From tablename 
join sourceTable On tablename.keyfield = sourceTable.keyField
Where sourceTable.jobname = @jobName
```